# How to add username to url in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect

Guys is there a way to get username of the logged in user and append it with site url such as [www.my-site.com/username](http://www.my-site.com/username)

How can we do this in functions.php?

Comment: Are you talking about having user profiles on frontend?

Comment: Yes. Basically i'm planning to redirect each logged in user to a custom made page that shows them their gallery only. Was confused how to proceed so this idea came in mind

Comment: By default WordPress doesn't have user profile pages so you probably should start by looking into membership / user profile plugins: https://wpeverest.com/blog/best-wordpress-frontend-user-profile-plugins/

Comment: It is possible to custom code them, too, but exact approach will be different, depenfing on your specs

Comment: I installed Frontend dashboard plugin. It gave me the option to add custom posts and chamge user profile data. But is there a way to create use specific pages. I wanna basically show each client that registers on my site his wedding photos on a random page

Answer (score 0):

```
/* you should try below code to get userid of logged in user and redirect to page with username in URL */
    
    $curret_usedata = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    if(!empty($curret_usedata)){
            $uname= $current_usedata->user_login;
            $redirectUrl = get_site_url().'/username='.$uname;
          
            /* redirect code here */

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that will help. Do you know what I can add into redirection code area